# how to rewrite SEO URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am just new to .htaccess.
I need some rewrite rules for URLs.
I Google'd some and applied but no change in URL.
I want:

```
demo.example.com/files/section.php?id=1
```

Changed to:

```
demo.example.com/sample-section
```

I tried

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `.htaccess` I assume you are using Apache. [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) you'll find all relevant documentation.

First of all you need the `mod_rewrite` module to be installed (instructions to do so depend on the server's operating system and Apache distribution).

Then, the URL rewrite is pretty simple:

```
# First of all tell to mod_rewrite to operate.
RewriteEngine  on

# Then, as many times you need, tell it on what to operate...
# For example: on files that do not exist. Or leave out RewriteCond to act on all.
RewriteCond   "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" !-f
# ...and what to do.
RewriteRule    /sample-section    "/files/section.php?id=1" [PT]
RewriteRule    /another-section   "/files/section.php?id=2" [PT]
```

[The PT (PassThru) flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) might be needed in some contexts, otherwise just use [L].